# Jquery link click does not work

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

```
each(data, function(i, elem) {
    var url = image_path + elem["c_no"] + "$" + elem["p_date"] + "$" + elem["time_slot"] + "$" + elem["d_name"] + ".jpg";
    var new_row = '<td  align="middle">' + elem["p_date"] + '</td>';
    new_row += '<td  align="middle">' + elem["d_name"] + '</td>';
    new_row += '<td  align="middle">' + '<a href="#" class="x"> AAAAA </a>' + '</td>';
    var appendRow = '<tr>' + new_row + '</tr>';
    $('#pres tr:last').after(appendRow);
});


$('table#pres td a.x').click(function() {
    console.log("ITWORKS");
});
```

i tried above code segment to display some links on a webpage dynamically.it works fine.but i need to do something after the link is clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do [Event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)  for dynamically added elements.

```
 $('table#pres').on('click','td a.x',function() {

    console.log("ITWORKS");

});
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('#pres').on("click", "td a.x", function() {
   console.log("ITWORKS");
});
```

This will attach `click` event handler for all existing and future created matching elements.